# listings-package custom language use space as comment-delimiter

Tags: listings, comments

I'm creating a custom language definition with the LaTeX [listings](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) package that should render Java's Jar-Manifest files (`key: value` Pairs) so that one can easily distinguish `key` and `value`.

My approach ("hacky" but alright for my problem) is to declare the space character as delimiter for comments (as `//` is in Java etc.) and style comments as normal text and normal text (what will everything left from the first space be - especially the `key:`) as keywords. So I'll even style multiline entries (by specification starting with a space) correctly. All by a one-line language definition.

**a part of a sample manifest file**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Description: The realization of the context bus on top of Sodapop
 7 as part of the universAAL Middleware (OSGi)
```

**my language definition**

```
\lstdefinelanguage{manifest}{
    morecomment=[l] % <-- this is the problem
}
```

My problem is: *how can I declare the space char as the delimiter for comments?*

Escaping it with a preceeding backslash (like recommended when using `#`, `&` or other TeX-reserved charaters) does not work. Hacking around with the unicode representation `U+0020` and the inputenc package does neither.

**Edit: Minimal Working Example**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{manifest}{
    morecomment=[l]: % works only for single-line entries, need 'space', not ':'
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=manifest, 
    basicstyle=\bfseries, 
    commentstyle=\normalfont]
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Description: The realization of the context bus on top of Sodapop
 7 as part of the universAAL Middleware (OSGi)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for single line comments:

```
morecomment=[l]{\ }
```